# Need to expand multiple lines with javascript, text overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/10h8t3ah/

```
function changeHeight(rowNum) {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.height= "70px";
  var fooBar = document.getElementById(rowNum);
  fooBar.style.height = "100px";
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to pass through a variable defined as row1, row2, row3, and row4 as rowNum and it will change the height of both the link and the paragraph with the corresponding row#.

I am trying to pass the ID of both the paragraph and the link so that if you hover over the link and vice versa, the height will change.

Essentially, if you hover over either the link or the paragraph, the corresponding containers side by side of each other will expand in height and the text in the paragraph will be visible. The paragraph text I have set with wrap-text property of break word but it seems to just overflow out anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - there are couple of concepts that need to be corrected to understand why this is not working:

1. **the `id` of a DOM object must be unique** *(your jsfiddle uses the same ID on both of your "rows" - I've updated your code to use a `class` instead of an id so that)*
2. the parameter you are passing to your `changeHeight` function must be a string (*if you pass `row1`, then `row1` must be a defined variable, instead you should pass `'row1`' -- again, see my updated fiddle code*)

#### Here is a jsfiddle that does most of what you want, I think : http://jsfiddle.net/zwyr4hn1/10/

There were also a couple of little things that I've fixed up:
 1. you need to return the other rows back to the smaller size when a new one is hovered *(I've used the class `row` on all the row objects to do this )* 2. this css is needed to get your `a` objects to resize in the way you want : `a { display: inline-block; }`

I haven't addressed the wrap-text issue you mentioned because I didn't see that on the jsfiddle.

Comment: Wow this is perfect! Thank you! I'm going to try and figure out the issues I'm having with wrap-text, it might have been an issue with unique ID, I re-wrote my actual code in the jsfiddle here to see if I did something wrong.

Comment: You are welcome.  Thanks for accepting the answer.  May I request an up-vote on the answer from you also?

Comment: But this is what I am talking about with the `word-wrap: break-word;` not wrapping, I included `display:inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/ux33e1s4/4/
I am trying to upvote everyone but I don't have the reputation

Comment: Reputation limits - of course - no worries.  For your wrapping issue, add the following to your CSS : `p: { word-break: break-all;
    white-space: normal;
    overflow: hidden; }`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of designing the complex JavaScript functions on your own, ust use accordion to expand the contents. Here's the Bootstrap framework accordions, especially designed for these purposes.

Link to page where you can learn more about it.

http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp